# PHP/MySQL Query, Count & Output

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I have a MySQL database with a `games` table. I also have `publishers` and `developers` tables. Each row in the games table has publisher and developer columns, which correspond with the other two tables.

- `games.Publisher` & `publishers.PublisherID`
- `games.Developer` & `developers.DeveloperID`

I'm trying to count the number of games each publisher and developer has, and display these with php into two tables on separate web pages. I know I need to create a loop to populate the number of games for each publisher/developer present in the table rows, but I can't figure out how.

Comment: What about to try some coding and post your code when you get stuck? Most of people don't have time to create it _completely_ for you.

Comment: Can you add your Mysql query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a count in SQL.

```
SELECT p.*, count(g.publisher) as number_of_games
FROM publishers p
LEFT JOIN games g ON (g.publisher = p.publisherID)
GROUP BY p.publisher WITH ROLLUP
```

This will give you the count per publisher with a total added to the bottom row.
If you just want the total, drop the last time from the query.

The query is the same for developers, just replace `publisher` with `developer`

**Links:**
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html
http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/

Comment: Thank you very much Johan, this worked perfectly. I have been trying to get the query right and failed miserably. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: You're welcome, feel free to accept the answer. A tip for next time, post the code that you've tried (and failed with), you'll get more answers that way; and maybe some new insights along the way.